# Should I create a composite index for every possible column combination?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a mysql db table that has fifteen columns. My web api will allow the user to search the table using any of the columns (each column could be used individually or with an combination of other columns).

My question is whether I should create create single instance indexes and then also multiple composite indexes to cover all the search combinations?

Whats the pros and cons?

As I understand the more indexes I create the worst performance for inserting/updates - but this table will only have its rows updated once a day.

PS the table size is in the region of 7 - 8k rows.

Comment: Test various sample queries with and without indexes.  Perhaps you don't need them at all.  The table is not that large.

Comment: thanks gordon. Are their any other general 'good practises' relating to index creation in this scenario?